# Process can write to docker volume on Windows not on Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I have an image based on [opencpu/base](https://hub.docker.com/u/opencpu/). It starts an apache based server, and then invokes R scripts everytime sombody calls an API endpoint.

One of those scripts tries to write a file to a location in the container. When I mount a folder into that location, it works on my Windows machine, but not on Ubuntu.

I've tried using named volumes on Ubuntu, but it does not work either. When I run bash inside the container interactively on Ubuntu, I can write and read the mounted volume just fine. But the apache process cannot.

Does anybody have some hints what could be going on here?

Comment: Check which user is running the apache process in the container (ps aux), that user must have access to read from the directory.

Comment: the user is www-data, how can I check if it has access?

Comment: I found out, and it works! thanks again! If you create an answer, I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log in interactively to the container, you will have root permissions.
Apache usually runs as another user (www-data), and that user must have read permissions on the folder that you want it to read.

Make sure that the permissions of the folder matches the user that will read it.